# Tinymce: How can I check if a window has been closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

Hi I have a plugin that opens a window with a own html-page.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('ds_format_edit', function (editor, url) {
editor.addMenuItem('ds_format_edit', {
    text: 'Formatvorlage anpassen...',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand("ds_format_edit");
    }

});

editor.addCommand('ds_format_edit', function () {
    editor.windowManager.open({
        title: "Formatvorlagen anpassen ...",
        url: 'DSFormatEditDialog.html',
        width: 800,
        height: 350,
        buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'OK',
                    onclick: function () {
                        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                    }
                },
                { text: 'Cancel', onclick: 'cancel' }
        ]
    }, {
        tinymce_formats: getFormats(),
    });
});
});
```

tinymce_formats is my parameter which I pass to the window. The dialog modify this parameter. All thats works.
Now I want to reintialize the tinymce editor if the window has been closed (if the user pressed the OK button) to get the modified parameter. 
**Is there any open callback function or an other way to realize that?**
Thanks Felix

**EDIT:**
I call this plugin with a Button. The Plugin open a window with a parameter. In this window I do something and modify the parameter. And if the window has been closed I want to use my reintialize function. I need a function which knows when the window is closed to execute the reintialize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset everything (button state & content) you need to unload the editor and initialize it again like this way :

```
# Remove TinyMCE instance
tinyMCE.remove();
# Initialize TinyMCE again
tinyMCE.init({ ... });
```

Or, if you only need to empty the text content, use this :

```
tinyMCE.get('#my-textarea-id').setContent("");
```

To tell to your main app the window has been closed, you can fire a custom event :

```
{
    text:'OK',
    onclick: function () {
        jQuery(document).trigger('myCustomCloseEvent');
        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    }
}
```

In you main app, bind the event :

```
jQuery(document).on("myCustomCloseEvent", function()
{
    alert('Window has been closed');
});
```

Comment: I know how I remove the editor. What I need is a function which execute if the window has been closed.

Comment: Oh. Just use the onclick callback you already defined on the OK button (answer updated).

Comment: Yeah but I can not access to my reintialize function at this position.
My reintialize function is implemented in the main code, not in the plugin.

Comment: You can fire a custom event from this callback in case you want dispatch to your main app. See ` jQuery.trigger`

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand this completly. Can I get an example pls?